# I asked for a too low salary at interview

Tags: salary

I just had an interview where I think I stated a too low salary expectation. The interviewer looked a bit puzzled and asked me if that was my current salary. I then went on to ask him to change that to a figure 5k higher (but I suspect that is still in their lower bracket).

This position has multiple rounds of interviews so I wont be receiving an offer just yet.
But if they do send me an offer does it makes sense to revise my salary demand higher then?

---

UPDATE : I asked for the salary I had in mind to begin with after they sent the final offer and I got it :)

Comment: When you say "too low" do you mean too low for you to live comfortably?  What exactly does "too low" mean to you?

Comment: Did you research typical salaries for the role beforehand? If not, did you research them afterwards? Is this a significant career change and/or advancement, or your first real job?

Comment: @sf02 I meant too low compared to what they were prepared to offer; i'm an architect in london and salary are professionwise very low compared to other professions unfortunately, but I was interviewing at a swiss firm (still ldn) and I think their salaries are higher. It's totally possible to live with it but it's quite a precarious lifestyle before you reach associate/director levels. I'm almost in my 40s and still sharing apartment...

Comment: @Comic Sans Seraphim yes I'm familiar with the salaries in the profession and that's in the range of what I asked. Their might be a premium at the position i applied for because it's a job for construction supervision / luxury project but aside from that i'd say it's just that company that has higher standards of salaries because the headquarter is in Basel.

Comment: Note that Greater London is the only place in the Western world where it is considered ok that an upper middle class academic job is not sufficient to pay for your own apartment. If the company is decent they will up their offer to something they consider enough for a reasonable living standard for an architect in Switzerland.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You write in comments that you researched salaries for your position and location, and that what you asked is in line with that. However you speculate that the company you applied to pays premium salaries because they are headquartered in Basel.

So far the only thing causing you to think that you might have undersold yourself is the interviewers reaction. Don't read too much into that.

If the company is that kind that expects to pay more than the market rate to get good people, they are usually the kind of company that pays you what they think you are worth even if you ask for less.

Also don't get sucked into the negotiation myth that you have only won if you extract every possible pound that the company is willing to pay you (and the company only wins if they hire you for the lowest possible salary you would have accepted). If you get offered a salary you are happy with, and higher than other positions you might have got, then it's a win. It doesn't matter what you might have got.

Answer (score 5):

You may endanger the opportunity by asking for more money - you've already done it once.  If you have other offers on the table and this one isn't high on your list, then sure, go ahead and ask for more money.  On the other hand, if your personal finances are in a crunch, it might be better to hold off on asking for more right now and see what comes across if the company presents you with an offer letter.

You're probably already aware that you sort of screwed yourself by making that initial low ball request.  Just don't repeat the mistake if this offer doesn't work out.

Comment: This question underscores the importance of knowing what you're worth in the job market.

Comment: @jwh20 D--n right about that!